# how to save = charactor in ini or cfg docement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ini, hibernate.cfg.xml

i want to save magnet link in ini document.Thus,it's inevitable that i have to  save "=" charactor in the file.However,python deem "=" charactor a "option to value" ,so python idle returns"configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from 'history.ini' [line  3]: option 'magnet' in section '0' already exists" when i use

```
configparser.ConfigParser().read('history.ini')
```

If you have any idea to deal with this problem ,please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem. I can save values containing `=` characters just fine:

test.ini

```
[Section]
Key=Val=ue
```

test.py

```
import configparser
cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
cp.read('ini.ini')
print(cp['Section']['Key'])  # Val=ue
```

I think the actual issue is just that you use the `magnet` key twice in the config (two lines which both start with `magnet=`).

If you want to have a list of multiple magnet links you can try using something like `magnet00000=`, `magnet00001=`, `magnet00002=`, and so on. Or switch to JSON.

Comment: Well,I turn to use text and my problem was solved ,but I still appreciate your help